# Getting the database name in hibernate query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

How to get the current database name in hibernate using named query..

I tried it like this,

```
String q1 = "select database()";
Query query1 = em.createQuery(q1);
String dbName = (String)query1.getResultList().get(0);
System.out.println("database name: "+dbName);
```

But this throws an error like this,

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /admin/user. Reason:

    No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'database' {originalText=database}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'

Caused by:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'database' {originalText=database}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
```

However if I run the same query in Sql GUI console it shows the current database name.

Comment: You might want to try using createNativeQuery() in this particular case

Comment: @Gimby yes it works after trying the createNativeQuery() method..thnks..

Comment: @Gimby can u post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
sessionFactory.getSettings().getConnectionProvider().getConnection().getMetaData().getURL();
```

Answer (score 0):

See this, the query is in postgres and may be slightly different in other db dialects. I used because i wasn't sure if i was connected to the right DB.

In rs.getString(1): I wrote "1" because postgres returns only 1 column. If your result is not giving the db name, you may use a for and print all columns (`for i=1 i<columnNumber; i++){print: rs.getString(i)}`), not only column 1 as i did.

```
    //session is the current Session name, of course
    return DatabaseSessionFactory.withSession(databaseConnector, (session) -> {
        session.doWork(new Work() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                Statement statement = null;
                try {
                    statement = connection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT current_database()"); //query for postgres
                    while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println("select current_database(): %s.",
                        rs.getString(1)); //in altri dialetti forse si deve fare for(i=1; i <X; i++)
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (statement != null) {
                        statement.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```